# Which values of $(a,b)$ make a function bijective/surjective/injective.

Tags: functions

I am doing exam revision and there's this problem in one topic on functions:

Suppose,

$f$ : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Find $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ : $f(x) = ax^3 -bx^2$ is,

- f is bijective.
- f is injective but not surjective.
- f is surjective but not injective.
- f is neither injective nor surjective.

The only method I've found helpful is essentially separating it into it's $x^2$ and $x^3$ components and then working out which values from there (either 1 or 0) yield these properties. I'm sure there is a more effective methods to find it out however.

Any advice/help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty here is that we have to consider only the four cases of a or b being equal on not equal to zero.

1) the function is injective $\Leftrightarrow a\neq 0\ $ and $\ ax^3-bx^2$ has exactly one solution $\Leftrightarrow a \neq 0,\ b=0 $

2) function is surjective $\Leftrightarrow a \neq 0 $

Combining the cases, we obtain:

- bijective: $ \ a \neq 0,\ b=0$
- injective but not surjective : no way
- surjective but not injective : $ \ a \neq 0, \ b\neq 0 $
- no injective, no surjective  : $ \  a = 0 $

Answer (score 0):

If $a\ne0$, then the function is surjective (consider the limits at $\pm\infty$).

If $a=0$, the function is neither injective nor surjective (why?).

For $f$ being bijective, the derivative must…

Comment: Doesn't $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$  imply there's a 1-1 mapping for every value of $\mathbb{R}$ when $a \neq 0$. In terms of when  $a = 0$, it's neither injective nor surjective since $0$ is mapped to all values of $y$ (which doesn't make it one-one). In terms of the derivative, it's monotonic so therefore not injective, therefore not bijective.

Comment: @Yaboy33 You have to think to $a$ and $b$ as being fixed. Each pair $(a,b)$ defines a function.

Answer (score 0):

** Hints**:

As $f$ is a differentiable function, ‘injective’ means ‘monotonic’, so itsderivative must have a constant sign, which isn't hard to test since it's a quadratic polynomial (at least if $a\ne 0$).

Also, by the *Mean value theorem*, a cubic polynomial function is always surjective from $\mathbf R$ to $\mathbf R$.